# Mat Table with sticky header and Horizontal ,vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-cdk

I have a mat table with sticky header and the vertical scroll of the page. It works fine until I add more columns dynamically and the horizontal scroll bar appears.

The sticky headers stop working.

is there any way to make it work?

Please see the example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdg9xh

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve - so there are few solutions. E.g. you can remove the wrapper altogether - this will make table overflow on both x and y to body, and body scrollbars will handle scrolling the data. Or, you could add height property to the wrapper (i.e. .example-container) and then wrapper will handle both x and y overflows. Basically, read up on how sticky works in conjunction with overflow - there a lot of good articles on that that will explain it much better than I could :)

Comment: Making container of fix height will fix the issue but my design is not allowing me to do the same. I want header sticky with page scroll in Y-direction and table scroll in x-direction as shown in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdg9xh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the width and height to the div container wrap around the mat-table. On stylesheet, you can apply something like this:

```
.example-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 32px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdg9xh-uxkaeh